# Eclipse Download library is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

I am trying to create my first JSF web dynamic project with eclipse. In second last step, i need to select the user library in which the download library window is empty. Can anyone help how to add the library in that?

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Click the floppy icon it would ask your to choose a provider. I have it in my workspace locatiion C:\Workspace_Jay\libraries\JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0)\mojarra-2.2.0-FCS\lib\javax.faces.jar after I downloaded it using the wizard for JSF project.

Comment: @Jay Ya once I added the proxy address, eclipse was able to get it from Internet.

Comment: Could it be a problem with proxy settings. Pls check this http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/

Comment: @Jay Yes it was :(. Now it got corrected

Comment: what proxy address needs to be added?

Comment: Also seing this but I'm not behind a proxy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to my machine was not able to connect to Internet. When i give the Preferences->Network Connections as Manual with a proxy, then it started appearing with user libraries.

[image: Screenshot results]

Comment: I have a direct internet connection and other parts of Eclipse that require a connection works fine (like Eclipse Marketplace), but the list is still empty. Any ideas ?

Comment: According to the Oracle, java.net site has closed.
http://www.oracle.com/splash/java.net/maintenance/index.html

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was, that I could select version 2.3 of JavaServer Faces, but that wasn't added to the download providers yet, that Eclipse can see. For older versions I could see the libraries.

[image: Project Facets Selection]