# unable to download mojarra for jsf

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

Earlier I was also getting an empty library
[Eclipse Download library is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658750/eclipse-download-library-is-empty)

I got the library after making the Network mode as "Manual" and setting the proxy but I am unable to Download it, after Accepting the License it gives Transfer Failed: java.net

Please help

Comment: why the downvote? very strange. If you need clarity..say so..or atleast give a reason for the downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing the same issue and are unable to understand why it was downvoted: Poting the Answer..I figured out that my Eclipse Network settings were hampering the download.. Go to Windows->Preferences->type Network Conenction in the Search Tab..Open it..Change the mode to NAtive..save and then checkout for Download Library in the Project Facets of your Project(CLick on Further configurations and Download Library.) Accept the License and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download JSF 2 jar file from here :
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.8/

Comment: boss.I already have the jsf jar in my buildpath, i need the content assist to give me autosuggestion on pressing Ctl+space and mojarra is not getting installed

Comment: @user2176576:than ask that immediately. And mojarra IS jsf, there is no mojarra FOR jsf