# Download Library is empty in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, jaxb

I was trying to create a new JAXB project. When choosing a User Library it shows no results as shown on the screenshot.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpLHy.png)

I found someone who had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658750/eclipse-download-library-is-empty). However playing with the proxy settings does not seem to fix the issue. Aswell as reinstalling eclipse. I am able to access the Eclipse Marketplace so it should not be an connection issue. Does anyone have an idea?

I tried changing the proxy settings and also changing settings in the Project Facets section.